# Insert credentials into HTTP string?

Tags: bash, shell-script, git

I need to insert user credentials into an HTTP string so I can properly populate my git credentials file at `~/.git-credentials`.

These are the three environment variables I have to start with:

```
user="someUser"
pass="somePass"
uri="http://sometld.org/path/repo.git"
```

I've been fiddling with `awk`, but it will only work with Github style cloning paths (`https://github.com/org/repo.git`) and won't work with non-standard paths (`https://git.private.org/scm/~user/path/repo.git`):

```
proto=$(echo $uri | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')
domain=$(echo $uri | awk -F"/" '{print $3}')
repo_path=$(echo $uri | awk -F"/" '{print $4}')
repo_name=$(echo $uri | awk -F"/" '{print $5}')
echo "$proto//$user:$pass@$domain/$repo_path/$repo_name"
# http://someUser:somePass@sometld.org/path/repo.git
```

What is the best/easiest way to insert a username and password into an HTTP string so I can populate my `~/.git-credentials` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -e "s^//^//$user:$pass@^" <<<$uri
http://someUser:somePass@sometld.org/path/repo.git
```

This replaces `//` with `//$user:$pass@` in the string `$uri` and will work anywhere.

In Bash specifically:

```
$ echo ${uri/\/\////$user:$pass@}
http://someUser:somePass@sometld.org/path/repo.git
```

[will perform the same replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) - this is just `${variable/pattern/replacement}`, but it's necessary to escape the slashes in the pattern because we can't change the delimiters here.

Comment: Oh, that is a brilliant way to do it. Perfect, thanks!